# Spring Integration Task Executor Memory Leakage

Tags: spring-integration

My module is on spring integration  which pushes message to RabbitMQ.

```
<task:executor id="bulkChannelExecutor" keep-alive="50" poolsize="50-100" queue-capacity="500"
></task:executor>   
    <int:channel id="logIngesterRestEndpointBulk"   >      
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="bulkChannelExecutor" failover="false" /> 
    </int:channel>

While Load testing ist not able to handle heavy loads(100 concurrent users) it causing message or request lost ,if i remove pool-size ,having unbounded poolsize its able to handling heavy loads but its creating memory thread leaks?
```

Rest Gateway will get input as Json and pass it to Filter and then will to
Chain ,there Json messages will get parsed and splitted as indivdiual messages and then will get push to rabbitMQ

```
<task:executor id="bulkChannelExecutor" keep-alive="50" pool-size="100-500"
    queue-capacity="500"
></task:executor>   
<int:channel id="logIngesterRestEndpointBulk"   >      
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="bulkChannelExecutor" failover="false" />  
</int:channel>
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="logIngesterGatewayBulk" auto-startup="true" 
    supported-methods="POST" request-channel="logIngesterRestEndpointBulk" 
    path="/rest/log/bulk" error-channel="errorChannel"  reply-timeout="50" 
    request-payload-type="java.lang.String">        
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
<int:channel id="filterChannelbulk">        
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="messageOutputChannel" >       
 </int:channel> 
<int:filter input-channel="logIngesterRestEndpointBulk"
    throw-exception-on-rejection="true" method="validate" ref="payloadValidation"
    output-channel="filterChannelbulk">
</int:filter>
 <int:chain input-channel="filterChannelbulk" output-channel="messageOutputChannel" id="chaining"  >
    <int:splitter id="splitter" ref="payloadSplitter" method="splitPayLoad"  >          
    </int:splitter>
    <int:transformer id="logMessageTransformerbulk" ref="logMessageHeaderTransformer"
        method="transform">
    </int:transformer>
</int:chain>
<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel"
    ref="responseHandler" method="handleFailedPayLoad"  >   
</int:service-activator>    
<!-- Start RabbitMQ Configuration -->
 <int:channel id="ackchannel">
</int:channel>
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter  
    id="amqpAdapter" channel="messageOutputChannel" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" lazy-connect="false" confirm-ack-channel="ackchannel"  confirm-correlation-expression="headers['amqp_publishConfirm']"     
    exchange-name="dhp_exchange" routing-key-expression="headers['routingKey']" >  
</int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator  id="ackservice" input-channel="ackchannel"  ref="responseHandler" method="confirmAck" />
```

Comment: You need to provide much more information. It generally means whatever you have downstream can't keep up with the upstream load. There are several techniques you can use to put back-pressure on message source, but you need to show all your configuration.

Comment: Thanks Gary,Here my configurations

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using HTTP, you should remove the task executor and allow the web container to manage the threads. If you need more threads, do it through the web container configuration; don't use a thread handoff here; it really serves no purpose and can cause the issues you describe.